# Rotate a PDF for readability

Tags: pdf

Someone sent me a pdf that's rotated 90 degrees and is thus difficult to read. How can I rotate it back?

Comment: What are you reading it with. More info is useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Adobe Reader, you can go to **View -> Rotate View** and choose between **clockwise** ( <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> ) and **counterclockwise** ( <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> ).

[image]

Comment: +1 for using the poignant guide as the example. we miss _why

Comment: Agreed. The work he did for the community was outstanding.

Answer (score 3):

Rotating the document in the PDF viewer may be sufficient, but if you want to persist the rotation you might want to use [pdftk](http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/).

The following command rotates the whole document to 90 degrees counterclockwise:
`pdftk in.pdf cat 1-endL output out.pdf`.

You can also specify more specifically which pages to rotate and to which direction, e.g. 2nd page 90 deg cw and 5th page upside down:
`pdftk in.pdf cat 1 2R 3-4 5D 6-end output out.pdf`.

The full reference to the rotational commands (and others) can be found at [pdftk's reference](http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/#docs).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [PDFill PDF Tools with FREE PDF Toolbox](http://www.pdfill.com/pdf_tools_free.html) :

> Free PDF Tools: Rotate and Crop PDF Pages
>
> You can rotate pages by 90, 180 and
>   270 degree from an Adobe PDF file into
>   a new file.

[image]

Comment: The installer for this program tried added at least three icons to my desktop and tried to install the JVM. It never said anything about this up front.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl+Right works well in foxit, sumatra, and evince, so I assume that it works in adobe as well.

Also, there's a menu option:
http://malektips.com/adobe_reader_7_0023.html

Answer (score 1):

Could just use an online tool like docq.com

Comment: I used http://www.rotatepdf.net/ and had luck with that. No guarantees, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

On a Macbook Pro you can just rotate the document with your fingers using the multitouch trackpad. Don't worry about rotating it exactly 90 degrees as it will automatically snap into place