# Rotate PDF document

Tags: pdf, batch, label, label-printer

We have created thousands of PDF files that are printed as a label on a special label printer. Printing these labels is ok, but some of the label paper are quarter turned and the PDF are printed incorrectly. There is a possibility to rotate the page before printing. But is it possible to rotate a PDF file and save it again as a PDF file? And there are thousands of PDF files, is it also possible to do this is a batch program?

Comment: You mean rotating all the pages 90 degrees?

Comment: Yes, I mean to rotate them 90 degrees.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rotate a PDF for readability](https://superuser.com/questions/59233/rotate-a-pdf-for-readability)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PDFill PDF Editor](http://www.pdfill.com/pdf_tools_free.html) and [RotatePDF.net](http://www.rotatepdf.net/) will allow you to (permanently) rotate PDFs.

Comment: PFDFill PDF Editor is the solution for us! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

On Linux/Unix you can use [pdfrecycle](http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/pdfrecycle/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have Adobe Acrobat Professional, you can rotate all pages of a PDF document from `Document > Pages > Rotate`. In order to "batch rotate" the PDFs, go to `Advanced > Batch Processing` and create a new sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use open source tools for that: 
either PDF Split and Merge, which is generally more robust: http://www.pdfsam.org
or PDF architect, whic has a nicer, though less stable GUI: http://www.pdfforge.org

However, take care about all the tickboxes in installers - they tend to include various browser addons you probably do not need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rotate pages in a PDF file without downloading and installing anything, try [DocDocGoose](https://docdocgoose.huey.xyz), an open source web app.

It processes the PDF file in your browser, so the file is never sent to a remote server.

Disclaimer: I am the maker of DocDocGoose.